# Laravel two routes with the same base pointing to different controllers?

Tags: php, laravel, url, routes

I have `/{country}/{city}` and `/{country}/{city}/{cat}` pointing to two different controllers. However the second one keeps returning 404. It does not get directed to the method in the controller. Can I not use that base structure twice for different controllers? Seems pretty weird.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that

`/{country}/{city}/{cat}`

is before

`/{country}/{city}`

in your routes.php. It will always look for the first matching ruleset.

Comment: Thanks that was one. 
Second problem was that I had another route `/{country_op}/{city_op}/{sthg_name}` will do `/{country}/{city}/category/{cat}`